# Rails, apply a scope or not depending on whether a parameter is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I've been running into this problem several times: I want to apply a scope on a query, but only if the parameter passed to the scope is not null. So

```
tags = Tag.where(name: params[:name]) if params[:name]
```

However, there are two problems with this. One is that Rails will evaluate the query immediately, and so if I want to apply more conditions to it, say

```
tags.where(location: params[:place]) if params[:place]
```

It will query the DB again. The second problem is that it doesn't look very nice, which I've tried to get around with class methods.

```
  class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.name_like this_name
      if !this_name.blank?
        where("name ILIKE '%#{this_name}%'")
      else
        #what do I put here? `all` does not work
      end
    end
  end
```

However, I cannot simply just put `all` in there, because that evaluates a query. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you can use a lambda scope, and use the `self` to call `self.all`:

```
  class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

    scope :named_like, (lambda do |name| 
      if name.present?
        where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{name}%")
      else
        scoped # does not apply a where clause
      end
    end)

  end
```

This is taking too much lines for a very basic scope, here is the compressed version:

```
class Tab < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :named_like, lambda{ |name| self.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{name}%") if name.present? }

end
```

Also:

- **Never use** direct **String interpolation inside a Where** clause: http://blog.presidentbeef.com/blog/2013/02/08/avoid-sql-injection-in-rails/

Comment: Aha! It works. Why can you string this together with other scopes in a lambda scope but you can't with class methods? For example, doing something like `Tag.name_like("stuff").where(...).all`......

Comment: Yes you can (Rails 3), chaining scope should be possible as far as the scopes / methods returns AR::Relations. (You don't need to call `all` at the end)

Comment: Yeah and additionally you can't call all. This solution only works if you don't, in fact. I just edited it to accept that

Comment: Nope. `all` seems to return an `Array`, whereas if you just execute `where`, you get an `ActiveRecord::Relation`

Answer (score 0):

For what I know (and what is writed here: [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database)), the query is actually performed ONLY when you iterate over the result. So, when you write something like:

```
tags = Tags.where(name: params[:name])
# other stuff here
tags = tags.where(location: params[:place])
```

In this snippet, no query is executed.

```
tags.each { # do something }
```

But there it is! Only once, of course.
In the first place, tags is an ActiveRecord::Relation object, and so you can
chain how much `where` you like.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. So I could keep everything as a class method.... I think..... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Exactly, if you need this kind of features in more than one place, you can pack it in a class method of the model :) But I think is better if you pass the `param` as an argument instead of use it directly.